# 3D Boxes (histograms) Gnuplot with cairolatex (or epslatex)

Tags: plot, latex, gnuplot, histogram

I would like to plot 3D graphics using histograms (3D boxes) in gnuplot. However I use epslatex or cairolatex, and the demonstrations I used from the gnuplot demo site use a command:

**set boxdepth**

And this command always gives the error in my script.

The image I want to get looks similar to this:
[image]
Image link: http://www.gnuplot.info/demo_cvs/3dboxes.html

My basic script is this:

```
# Change filename to whatever you want.
filename = "fig4"

# LaTeX amsmath and utf8 input support.
set terminal cairolatex size 9cm,9cm color colortext standalone lw 4 header  \
    "\\usepackage{amsmath}\
     \\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}"

# Don't change output name
set output "gptemp.tex"

unset key

splot 'data.dat' with boxes


set out
system sprintf("pdflatex\
    -interaction batchmode gptemp.tex &&\
    mv gptemp.pdf %s.pdf &&\
    rm -f gptemp*", filename)
```

Answer (score 2):

The capability to draw 3D boxes is new, and only present in the gnuplot development version (5.3).

Comment: This seems better-suited as a comment.

Comment: The docs (tmacchant3.starfree.jp/gnuplot/Eng/cygbin/gnuplot.pdf, page 124) say the option is valid.  But gnuplot reports an error ("unrecognized option") when I run a plotting script I found on the web, one that specifically uses boxdepth.